# Rspec DB View Is Empty

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I created a `LeadIndex` view within my Rails application that is based on my `Lead` model. When running my test suite (Rspec) the table (db view) is recognized but returns as an empty `[]` of `LeadIndex::ActiveRecord_Relation`. The `Lead` model is showing that there are objects stored within the database, but the view doesn't seem to pick it up.

For example:

```
Lead.all =>

[#<Lead:0x000000010a70a9a8
  id: 850,
  source: "Web",
  user_id: nil,
  created_at: Tue, 12 Oct 2021 18:48:32.505988000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 12 Oct 2021 18:48:32.521121000 UTC +00:00,
  received_on: Tue, 12 Oct 2021 00:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00,
  assigned_on: Tue, 12 Oct 2021 00:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00,
  agency_id: 452,
  person_id: 882,
  age: 41,
  status: "prospecting",
  dnc: false,
  last_contact_time: nil>]
```

```
LeadIndex.all  => [] # actual

LeadIndex.all => #expected
[#<LeadIndex:0x000000015221ed48
 id: 850,
 source: "Web",
 user_id: nil,
 created_at: Tue, 12 Oct 2021 18:48:32.505988000 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 12 Oct 2021 18:48:32.521121000 UTC +00:00,
 received_on: Tue, 12 Oct 2021 00:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00,
 assigned_on: Tue, 12 Oct 2021 00:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00,
 agency_id: 452,
 person_id: 882,
 age: 0,
 status: "prospecting",
 dnc: false,
 last_contact_time: nil,
 scheduled_time: nil,
 name: "John Doe",
 person_state: "TX",
 number: "(555) 555-5555",
 num_outbound_dials: 3,
 last_activity: Tue, 12 Oct 2021 00:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00,
 agent_name: "Tom Cruise",
 lang: "English",
 next_dial_time: "morning">
irb(main):002:0>]
```

In development mode everything works perfectly.

Comment: You are a little short on details, please see [ask]. In particular you need to post actual query, table definition(s) (ddl), sample data and expected results, all as text - **no images**.

Comment: I've updated the original post. Hope this helps. It seems like it has to be an Rspec configuration issue. Since it seems to work fine within development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am a knucklehead. I figured it out for me. In my SQL query I hard a where clause to bring up results only with an ID that matches my development DB object.

So when when the test environment made up random IDs for their objects the WHERE clause was filtering out all of them because there was no ID with the exact number that matched my development DB id..

a big d'oh! Lessons learned.